# Python CSV Write Only Specific Rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split, python-itertools

I'm attempting to read a CSV file that has several lines of useless data at the start and extract only the lines that contain relevant data. I've tried tens of variations of my code and tried implementing it with libraries like Pandas, but haven't had any success. An example CSV reads as follows, with the first 5 lines containing data I don't need. The only lines I want to write to a new file being the lines after "SOLUTION".

```
MWU Checker - 09/12/2018
Server v7.4,Admin,Product
RECOMMEND
Update,Issue Statement,Bypass,Resolution
SOLUTION
IP Address,DNS Name,OS,Status
10.0.0.1,win08a,Windows Server 2008 R2,Up to date
10.0.0.2,win08b,Windows Server 2008 R2,Up to date
10.0.0.3,win08c,Windows Server 2008 R2,Out of date
10.0.0.4,win08d,Windows Server 2008 R2,Up to date
10.0.0.5,win08e,Windows Server 2008 R2,Up to date
```

Given that "SOLUTION" will always be on line 5, I've tried to write to a CSV with the following code:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

def checker():
    with open('sample_file.csv', 'r') as csv_in, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_out:
    data = csv.reader(islice(csv_in, 5, None), delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    for row in data:
        print (row)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

What's so frustrating is that the console will print out the correct data, showing only lines 6 or greater, but the writer never updates the "output.csv" file, it simply writes the exact same data as what was in the original "sample_file.csv".

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but I've tried countless variations of my code and attempted it in Pandas as well, but found that Pandas doesn't work as nicely when you have strangely formatted CSVs such as these.

Comment: I think your code works. When I ran it I couldn't reproduce your issue. `output.csv` only contained the rows printed to stdout. Are you sure you aren't blasting over `output.csv` in some other part of your program?

Comment: @MattMessersmith You're right! Another part of my program was executing without me even realizing it. In hindsight, I probably should have ripped out my above code and tested it in isolation, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Reading out just the data lines and storing into a pandas dataframe should work with this:

```
import pandas as pd    

df = pd.read_csv('sample_file.csv', skiprows=5)
```

which can be followed by writing out to new csv file with:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```